# how to tail mssql server logs in linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, trace

I want to monitor all queries on ms sqlserver database.

How to see and trace microsoft sql server logs via `tail` command in linux?

I use the following command to see postgresql logs:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

Comment: Is your question about the default SQL Server error log location on Linux? It's `/var/opt/mssql/log` so the tail command would be `sudo tail -f /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`

Comment: No, I basically want to monitor all queries.

Comment: SQL  Server doesn't log all queries by default. You could do that with an extended event trace (perhaps filtered for long-running ones to avoid unwanted noise) or enable the query store for historical aggregate query stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [azure-data-studio profiler extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-ver15) to tracing queries.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to monitor all queries on ms sqlserver database.

SQL Server doesn't log all queries by default. You could do that with an [extended event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15) trace (perhaps filtered for long-running ones to avoid unwanted noise) or enable the [query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) for historical aggregate query stats.